# How to make a javaScript variable equal to something or something else?

Tags: javascript

Trying to add randomness to which image is displayed. Issue with saying calling and or statement.

```
var image = url3 | url2 | url1;
    buildImage(image);



function buildImage(imagesrc) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imagesrc;
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
```

Comment: You want to pick a URL at random from an array?

Comment: You have a very confused understanding of what `OR` means in programming. It's not how you make a collection of things, it's a boolean or binary operation.

Comment: @Barmar In fairness, if this was SML, `datatype image = url1 | url2 | url3` would be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = [url3, url2, url1];
var image = images[(Math.random() * images.length)|0];
```

The "or" operators are not probabilistic "or" that will return one value or another. They are very specific: `||` will return the first value unless it's falsy, in which case it returns the second; and `|` converts both arguments to integers and applies the same operation to each individual binary digit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using separate variables, make a `urls` array:

```
var urls = [
    "http://example.com/img1.jpg",
    "http://example.com/img2.jpg",
    "http://example.com/img3.jpg"
];
```

You can then select a random URL by doing:

```
var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];
```

And call `buildImage`:

```
buildImage(url);
```